# Use GPG to Password Protect .GZ file

Tags: linux, unix

I've created a compressed tar file, abc.gz.  I want to password protect the abc.gz file and I've used GPG in the past, but it's not working for me now.  I don't understand why its asking for a user id and empty line.  Do I have the correct syntax?  I'm using Linux 32 bit OS

**gpg command:**

```
$ gpg -e abc.gz
You did not specify a user ID. (you may use "-r")

Current recipients:

Enter the user ID.  End with an empty line:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may look for this:

```
gpg -c abc.gz
```

The `-e` option tells `gpg` to encrypt a file using a specified key, so that only the only of that key can decrypt it.  The `-c` option uses a "symmetric cipher", so it can be decrypted with just a passphrase.